# get the lamp status of Onvif camera

Tags: onvif

I have an onvif camera and a toggle button to turn the lamp on and off. I use the tt:lamp|on style of commands sent to the Onvif endpoint. Is there a way to query the status of the camera and retrieve weather or not the lamp is on?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the camera side events via the [ONVIF event service](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/events/wsdl/event.wsdl) and check if the camera is sending the current lamp status in the event stream. Most devices will give you a full initial state of all the things they can report through the event service as a response to the first `PullMessage` request.